# Run ffmpeg command line error in android

Tags: android, ffmpeg

When i run this code:

```
String cmd = mFfmpegInstallPath+" -f image2 -i "+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/ffmpeg/img%03d.png "+Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/tmp/out.mp4";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);
```

I got a error:

> Working Directory: null Environment: null

So how to run ffmpeg command line in android?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot execute binaries on android you need to use some c library.

Check this repo it might be helpful:
https://github.com/guardianproject/android-ffmpeg

Comment: I follow this link https://github.com/JayH5/android-ffmpeg-cmdline   it seem to do it,so i run the code above.but it run failed!

Comment: That lib looks nice too, btw you should add a space to make the link clickable.